# Zend_ACL - Cannot use my current model with it, I think I'm doing MVC the wrong way here

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db-table, zend-acl

I've just started using Zend_ACL to restrict access to certain controllers based on user roles. Its working pretty fine except however now I need to set it up so that users can only access their own records. For example my application allows people to make bookings. I need to restrict using ACL that users can only view their own bookings on the application while administrators can see all bookings.

I read about using assertations but some how I think I've been using my models the wrong way. Here is how I set up a typical model.

```
<?php

class Model_Bookings extends Zend_Db_Table {

  //class Variable
  protected $_name = 'bookings';
  protected $_primaryKey = 'id';

  function _toArray($a, $index='id', $value='title') {
  }

  function add($data) {
  }

  function update($data) {
  }

  function delete($id) {
  }


  function get($id = false, $options = false) {

  }

}

?>
```

The model in this case doesn't correspond to a single instance of the booking object :( how can I use such a model in this case when restricting views using ACL i.e how can I set it up so that when the user goes to list of bookings he sees only his bookings. Do I need to do some major refactoring here? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid I'm not answering your question, but here are some really good articles to read. Maybe you'll find help there :

- http://codeutopia.net/blog/2009/02/06/zend_acl-part-1-misconceptions-and-simple-acls/
- Maybe you can read french ? -> http://www.kitpages.fr/fr/cms/89/initiation-a-zend_acl

Comment: Maybe you could explain what helped you into the articles I gave you to read ? It would be more helpful to others...